# Where to find documentation/tutorials on ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

It looks like the final release for ASP.NET MVC 2 has been already around for 2 weeks. Unfortunately, I can't find documentation that's intended for MVC 2 exclusively. I've checked Amazon.com (no book yet on MVC2), ScottGu's Blog (only 2 short posts), ASP.NET/MVC website (they've only posted what are alreadi in the ScottGu's blog).

Any idea where to find matter on MVC2?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation is [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520618%28VS.100%29.aspx), and in VS 2010 help.

Answer (score 2):

Best place to get updated information about asp.net mvc is below site

http://asp.net

Answer (score 1):

- [Upgrade from MVC 1 to 2 (documentation)](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes/)
- [Upgrade from MVC 1 to 2 (tool)](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx)
- [Phil Haack has some good posts on MVC 2](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/03/12/ms-pl-source-release-for-system-web-mvc-2.aspx)

and as Hiscal said, http://asp.net is a great resource too. What I've done is use MVC 1 documentation while familiarizing myself with the new features of MVC 2 via [Phil Haack's](http://haacked.com), [ScottGu's](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/), and [Hansleman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its just me, but all these sites just talk in general about mvc 2 - its being released soon, download here, read this blog (which just says the same). I've yet to find any real code/implementations of areas, validation, or templates. Guess I need to google harder.

Also http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/A-First-Look-at-ASP-NET-MVC-2.aspx

Comment: and http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html